# ionic2 chrome debug no typescript

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a new ionic2 project using ionic version 2.1.12.
After running this
command

> ionic serve

using chrome to debug, but I can't find the typescript file

[image: here is a screen shot].

My ionic-app-script version is 0.0.46, I've searched all day, can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the (no domain) and scroll down after the node modules.

Comment: The ts file was found in the (no domain),but why?how can I move this to a specify file

Answer (score 0):

Update latest ionic-app-script:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Comment: no this will lead to unmet dependency with ionic 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Set the source map in the package.json

`"config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
  }`

According to the link -
[Custom Configuration App Scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration)

In case anyone is using vscode for development,
this is a useful link: [debug typescript in vscode](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-debug-typescript-in-ionic-2-apps-using-vs-code-and-app-scripts-0-0-46/70023)

Comment: Same problem here. Did what you suggested. But getting exactly the same problem.

Comment: After add this to my package.json,now I can see the ts file in the build directory,but there are too many js files in this folder,can I move this ts files out of this folder,make a src file just like the Demo folder structure.Thanks.

Comment: @Tong can you run ionic info and share the output?

Comment: Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
@pantonis here it is

Comment: @Tong and your package.json please?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not

Answer (score 0):

if ionic serve leads to a blank page  then make sure that your package.json have all the below mentioned contents....(inside scripts)

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
"serve:before": "watch",
"emulate:before": "watch",
"deploy:before": "build",
"build:before": "build",
"run:before": "watch"

  }
```

Comment: I added this to my package.json file,then run (npm install),after that,rerun (ionic serve).The browser link become http://ipaddress:8100,that used to be http://localhost:8100.Why this happened? Thank very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's work for me.

Add the **config** to your package.json

```
  "description": "my-side-menu: An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
  },
```